# X-Input controller doesn't work

Tags: xubuntu

I am having issues with using my wired X-Input controller with GalliumOS on my HP Falco Haswell. It is not recognized nor does it display inputs in the terminal, even to where I tried installing drivers and responses with no success. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my output from dmesg

```
[30079.190473] wlp1s0: associated 
[30518.590135] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd 
[30518.759661] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=055b 
[30518.759672] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
[30518.759683] usb 1-2: Product: Gamesir-G3w 
[30518.759685] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Xiaoji 
[30518.785813] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina 
[30518.795610] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid 
[30518.795612] usbhid: USB HID core driver 
[30518.804328] input: Xiaoji Gamesir-G3w as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:05AC:055B.0001/input/input14 
[30518.804518] hid-generic 0003:05AC:055B.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Gamepad [Xiaoji Gamesir-G3w] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0 
[30518.815032] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 26 
[30519.460090] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd 
[30519.630202] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=20bc, idProduct=5500 
[30519.630214] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
[30519.630224] usb 1-2: Product: Gamesir-G3w 
[30519.630226] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Xiaoji
```

Comment: Did you disconnect the device yourself, or did it disconnect on its own? If the latter, then it may not get enough power via USB for some reason. If the former, it registers as HID device and with the input layer, so you should be able at least to see events with `evtest`.

Comment: I don't see it in evtest, and I connect the device myself.

Comment: Then it's a USB communication problem, and as I said, the first thing to check is power issues. If you have a powered hub, try to connect it via that hub when it's powered.

Comment: Where can you get one?

Comment: Everywhere where you can buy computer parts or electronics, e.g. [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb+hub+powered). But it's for testing, you don't have to buy one especially just for that. Maybe you can borrow one somewhere? If the problem is something else, it won't help.

Comment: The controller somehow miraculously worked out of nowhere, (LED lit for a few seconds). Once I connected it once more, it gave me errors. And then after reconnecting stopped giving me errors. You can use this Pastebin as a reference. (Scroll all the way to the bottom)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25623053/

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a problem with the USB communication: You get random read errors and disconnecnts from time to time.

Possible reasons:

- Insufficient power to the USB device.
- Bad cable, or cable close to something that produces electromagnetic interference.
- Hardware fault in the USB device.
- Sometimes a particular USB host controller just won't work with a particular USB device (timing? I've seen this, but not explanation for it).
- Something else.

Try to test systematically: Connect the device to other USB ports on the same computer, or to another computer. Use a different cable. As I wrote, if you have one or can borrow one, connect it behind a powered hub.

If it turns out that the hardware of the X-input controller is faulty, you just may have to return it and get another controller if you still have warranty.

Comment: The controller had worked just fine with every other computer, even on this very same one. Though, it had crouton with the regular Ubuntu distro. It is only GalliumOS that won't let it work.

Comment: Also, power seems to be supplied since the controllers LED buttons are lit up.

Comment: If the same type of error never happened before on this very same computer, with everything else the same except OS, then I don't know. (The point about power is not "there is power", but "occasionally it draws more current than the host hardware supplies, that causes the voltage to drop, and that generates faults and disconnects". So "the controllers LED buttons are lit up" doesn't mean anything).

Comment: I have fixed it by installing the unity distro, or regular Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: So it looks like a bug in the Gallium OS USB drivers ...